# Hortonworks 2.6.5 yum install python-pip not working

Tags: python, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to install python pip on HDP2.6.5, but its constantly failing with Error 403.

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.5.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.



 One of the configured repositories failed (HDP-2.6-repo-1),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=HDP-2.6-repo-1 ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable HDP-2.6-repo-1
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=HDP-2.6-repo-1

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=HDP-2.6-repo-1.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from HDP-2.6-repo-1: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.5.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks repos have been behind a pay wall for the last few years, so installing or upgrading of packages within the sandbox will no longer work.